# Refrigerating after reheating?

Tags: reheating, food-safety

Yesterday, I got a calzone from a pizzeria, took it home and refrigerated it immediately.

This morning, I reheated it in the microwave and ate some. Then, I put it back in the fridge. Later today, I reheated it again in the microwave and ate the rest.

Now besides poor food quality (which it was), was this "okay" to do as far as health/bacteria is concerned?

I did a search for this but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same answer as always:  you don't want to eat any perishable food or food for which any part has spent more than about 4 hours *cumulative over its lifetime* in the danger zone (40 - 140 F, 4 - 60 C).

Do you know how the pizza place treated the calzones before you even received it?  It may have been sitting on a shelf at room temperature for an hour or two at the store before you ordered it, in addition to the transport time when you took it home, and all the times as you heated and cooled it when it was in the zone.

In general to reduce the quality degradation, and the amount of time food ends up moving through the danger zone, you normally only want to heat up the portion of food you intend to eat, and leave the rest refrigerated.

See also:  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info

Comment: Well it was salami/pepperoni, so I believe don't those types of meat have less bacteria potential. Since they are already semi-cooked to begin with?

Comment: They are cured meats, and due to the salt levels, perhaps less potentially hazardous than other foods, but there are still other ingredients such the cheese and eggs that are the limiting factors.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ The linked article says food should remain in the danger zone no longer than 2 hours cumulative. If that's correct, you might want to edit your answer.

Comment: Sorry, you will find both 2 hours and 4 hours used by the FDA in different contexts...  its a crazy world.